# What is the proper notation for a function of a function?

Tags: functions, notation

Let $\mathcal{F} : A \to F$ be a function, and $ f = \mathcal{F}(a)$.

$\big($with $a\in A$ and $f\in F$$\big)$.

Now, let $f : X \to Y$ itself be another function, and $y = f(x)$.

$\big($with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$$\big)$.

What is the adequate notation to write:

$y = f(x) \overset{?}{=} \mathcal{F}(a)(x)$.

Thanks for your answers.

NS

Comment: Do yo mean that $F$ is a set of functions ?

Comment: To avoid confusion you can define $\mathcal{F}(a)=\mathcal{F}_a$ and write $ y=\mathcal{F}_a(x)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes it is.

Comment: @EmilioNovati that is what I did, in fact; but I am wondering if there exists a standard way to write $\mathcal{F}(a)(x)$.

Comment: In order to avoid confusion, you can put parentheses around things too, e.g. $(\mathcal{F}(a))(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three commonly-used notations in math:
$$
\mathcal{F}(a) = f \ \ \text{ where } \ \ f(x) = a+x \\
\mathcal{F}(a)(x) = a+x \\
\mathcal{F}(a) = x \mapsto a+x
$$
and one in computer-science (I give two examples, but it is the same notation):
$$\mathcal{F}(a) = \lambda x.\ a+x\\
\mathcal{F} = \lambda a.\ \lambda x.\ a+x$$
and you can note the corresponding types as, for example, $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ or $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{R} \to (\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R})$.

Each of these define $\mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}(0)$ is the identity function, and $\mathcal{F}(1)$ is the add-one function on $\mathbb{R}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$